# Android - How to get usage/screen time for each app?

Tags: android

I downloaded an app that records screen time for your phone and each of your apps, but to my surprise, the app had detailed screen time for the current day and the previous week, even though I just installed the app for the first time. My current guess is that screen time is actually recorded by Android System, so my question is how do I access this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this information from [`UsageStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager).  The `UsageStats` it returns has methods like [`getTotalTimeInForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats#getTotalTimeInForeground()) that can supply that data.