# How i can get on screen time for current day in andriod studio using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i am using thing approach .

fun showtime()

{

```
    val end =System.currentTimeMillis()
    val start:LocalDateTime=LocalDate.now.atStartOfDay()
    val usageStatsManager = getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
    val stats = usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(start, end)

    val total  = Duration.ofMillis(stats.values.map { it.totalTimeInForeground }.sum())
    tvUsageStats.setText("YOU SPENT ${total} Hours.")
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100402/android-how-to-get-usage-screen-time-for-each-app

Comment: but it is not returning correct value

Comment: Well what is the number it's giving you. Unless you have else where, I don't see any conversions. If returning the time in millisecond then to get the hour you have to convert the milliseconds to hours. There is 3,600,000 milliseconds in one hour. So if your returning milliseconds do the conversion. I have to do this a lot coding in C#, however it would be the same in any language unless you use a Library

Comment: i am converting it to hours still its showing wrong value

Answer (score 0):

Since the api is not working for you, then you can do the calculation on your own. You will need 2 fields: startTime and elapsedTime

When you want to start recording time, initialise elapsedTime to 0 (this will be a default value from a shared preference) and startTime to System.currentTimeMillis()

When onPause() is called, you will call the following:

```
elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

and then save your elapsedTime to a sharedpreference.

Then you can transfrom the millis to seconds hours or whatever you need.

Comment: can you provide me solution in code (kotlin)

Comment: if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
            var startTimer = System.currentTimeMillis()

        } else if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) {
           var  endTimer = System.currentTimeMillis()
            var screenOnTime = endTimer - System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (screenOnTime < TIME_ERROR) {
                times.plus(screenOnTime.toString())
            }

Comment: how can i then print the result

Comment: By using a textview?